# Access action props in @ngrx effect with ofType for multiple actions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I have 2 Actions and an Effect for these 2 actions using `ofType` operator as below:

```
export const myActions = {
  actionA: createAction(`actionA`, props<{ a: string }>()),
  actionB: createAction(`actionB`, props<{ b: number }>())
}

myEffect$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(myActions.actionA, myActions.actionB),
    mergeMap(action => {
      // How to convert action object to correct type and access action.a or action.b props?
      if (action.type == myActions.actionA) {
        console.log(action.a); // compile error
      } else if (action.type == myActions.actionB) {
        console.log(action.b); // compile error
      }
    })
  ), {dispatch: false}
);
```

How can I check and access props of actions (action.a and action.b) and with auto-completion from IDE?

Comment: Why not just create 2 effects?

Comment: what about redux dev tools? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en

Comment: @timdeschryver Why not just create 2 effects? => I need the value from actionA and actionB for the same logic after that. In the example, I simplified to 2 actions. But I need actually 5 actions with the same logic and don't want to create 5 effects.

Comment: @PrzemyslawJanBeigert I use console.log just for example. In real life, I use for other purposes.

Comment: @XuanDaiNguyen please **include** some of the logic which requires sharing - if the props are of different types you'd have deal with this regardless of the fact this is in an effect similar to overloading a method

Comment: @AndrewAllen This question is about coding technique regardless of logic. And it is answered by PrzemyslawJanBeigert.

Comment: @XuanDaiNguyen than the answer is *it depends* but that you should have a good reason for not using 2 effects. Potential alternative 3 effects, 2 mapping to a common action with same props type, 1 effect implements common action. Unable to explore without concrete idea

Comment: @AndrewAllen I already answered the question "Why not just create 2 effects?" from timdeschryver in the comment above, please check again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ofType` takes as generic params type of action e.g. `ofType<Action>(actionType)` then merge map argument will be typed as `Action` without typing.

In your case `action` argument can be `ActionA` or `ActionB` as well, so you have to write `ofType<ActionA | ActionB>(actionTypeA, actionTypeB)`, then `action` from mergeMap will be typed as Union of `ActionA` and `ActionB`. But in proper if's branches like `(action.type == myActions.actionA)` action will be only `ActionA` typed, because TS complier understand some of ifs statement.

BTW advice of @timdeschryver to split it into 2 effects is very good.

==============edited=================

If you're defining action by `export const actionA = createAction('actionA', props<{ a: string }>())` you can declare type of `ActionA` by `type ActionA = ReturnType<typeof actionA>;`. `ReturnType` is generic added to TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I use `createAction('actionA', props<{ a: string }>())`, so how could I define type `ActionA`?

Comment: I added description to `edited` section . Please let me know if this answer your question/

Comment: Thank a lot! It works!
`type ActionA = ReturnType<typeof actionA>;`
`console.log((action as ActionA).a)`

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks!